# mmh3 not installed on Elastic MapReduce in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

I need to use mmh3 for hashing. However, when I run 
"python MultiwayJoin.py R.csv S.csv T.csv -r emr > output.txt" in terminal, it returned an error said that:

File "MultiwayJoin.py", line 5, in 
import mmh3
ImportError: No module named mmh3

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pip install mmh3` to install it.